# Java Multithreading with GUI (Kind of Traffic Simulator)

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I need to implement a solution for a narrow bridge and i am new to java threads and gui.
I have three roads and 1 bridge(has two lane).20 Vehicles for each road should be created randomly and should get passed to bridge depending of the light on its road.

**But first I just wanna solve an easy issue which is how can i move a car on this road with thread?(Sleep 1 second and move little bit.)**

**I thought like that:**
I have created the roads with simple PaintComponent function override(I am not sure if its gonna  be implemented like that too).
Created a road class and a vehicle class which implements runnable.
I created an array of 20 vehicles in Road class and stuck here.

How should I add this to a JPanel and move it right every 1 seconds?
Am I totally wrong about how to implement that problem  because i have background on C family ?

My Code:

public class NarrowBridge {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
    PanelSetter newPanel = new PanelSetter();
    myFrame.add(newPanel);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setSize(600, 600);
    myFrame.setTitle("Narrow Bridge Problem ");

    myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//To centralize the jframe.
    myFrame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

class PanelSetter extends JPanel {

```
public Road Road1 = new Road(true);
public Road Road2 = new Road(false);
public Road Road3 = new Road(false);

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);


    //Fixed Roads Drawing.
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(50, 100, 200, 100);
    g.drawLine(50, 130, 200, 130);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(50, 210, 200, 210);
    g.drawLine(50, 240, 200, 240);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(50, 320, 200, 320);
    g.drawLine(50, 350, 200, 350);


    //Road 1 Light.
    if (Road1.getLight()) {

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(180, 70, 20, 20);

    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(180, 70, 20, 20);

    }
    //Road 2 Light.
    if (Road2.getLight()) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(180, 180, 20, 20);

    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(180, 180, 20, 20);

    }
    //Road 3 Light. 
    if (Road3.getLight()) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(180, 290, 20, 20);

    } else {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(180, 290, 20, 20);

    }

}
```

}

Road is  just a simple  class which only has boolean light and the thing i tried which is vehicle[] vehicles=new vehicle[20].

Comment: what is Road here? paste your class

Comment: @Shriram I added its content but its nothing more than a standard basic class. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved my problem with the help of Java Applets.
I am able to pass the applet as a parameter and I am calling it's paint() function and updating screen.

Comment: Hi @Steven94, I have written it ages ago so It could be hard to understand.
But give it a try. Here: https://github.com/AkpolatKadir/NarrowBridgeProblem